# Market share based on comparison of competitors' average sales

Tags: sample-size

I want to determine the amount of food stamp fraud a retailer perpetrated based on food stamp sales in other stores. The retailer had both legitimate food stamps sales, and illegitimate sales. The illegitimate sales consisted of food stamps used to buy ineligible items or whee food stamps were illegally redeemed for cash.

I know the total amount of food stamps sales, but that figure reflects the total of all legitimate and illegitimate sales. Can an average of food stamp sales from other stores be compared to the retailer in a way that is statistically accurate? If so how big must that sample of other stores be?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

If the proportion of illegitimate sales were known to be the same in all stores, then your problem would be strictly a statistical one.  As it is, it's first and foremost a matter of content knowledge:  on what bases are you able to estimate the proportion in this store as compared to in others?  Do you have any other evidence to bring to bear on this situation?  Others more skilled in Bayesian methods will be able to give you specific steps to take so that you can create a credible interval for the proportion in the store in question.